# How to check current running version of the WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How do I check which version of WSO2 API Manager I'm currently running in my RHEL 7 machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the logs, you can check, when all the logs are loaded at the end it shows which version is of the API manager

\wso2am-3.0.0\bin>wso2server.bat --version

Result:

WSO2 API Manager v3.0.0
WSO2 Carbon Framework v4.5.1

Comment: Isn't there any file that indicates version or some command?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to request it to the endpoint available for this porpouse and it is usually used for health checking:

```
curl -X GET https://localhost:9443/services/Version
```

Response:

```
<ns:getVersionResponse xmlns:ns="http://version.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
<return>WSO2 API Manager-2.6.0</return>
</ns:getVersionResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a version.txt file in the <AM_HOME>/bin directory. You can refer to this file as well.